# Is it possible to match UI elements by labels using regex in XCUIElementQuery?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I'm currently learning how to create UI Tests in XCode.

I use XCUIElementQuery to locate alert and close it

```
let dismissSavedPasswordButton = app.alerts["Select a Saved Password to Use With “My App”"].buttons["Not Now"]
```

But for older devices (e.g. running iOS 9), this code should look like this

```
let dismissSavedPasswordButton = app.alerts["Select a Saved Safari Password to Use With “My App”"].buttons["Not Now"]
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code to make it universal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible if you extend `XCUIElementQuery` class. I do something similar in my code:

```
extension XCUIElementQuery {

    func softMatching(substring: String) -> [XCUIElement] {

        return self.allElementsBoundByIndex.filter { $0.label.contains(substring) }
    }
}
```

After that, you can match elements like this:

```
 let dismissSavedPasswordButton = app.alerts.softMatching(substring: "Password").first!.buttons["Not Now"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a regex, but should work:

```
app.alerts.element(boundBy: 0)
```

Since you should have only one alert on the screen, just query it by position.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

Should I consider using
    app.alerts.firstMatch
to make code run faster?

Comment: Yes, you could. But please consider reading **note** for the `firstMatch`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/2902250-firstmatch

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have more than one not now button on the screen you could just use

```
app.buttons["Not Now"]
```

You don't need to specify any more than that.